# Проблема с переменными PHP

Tags: php, массивы, фильтр

Поле `dateevent` содержит значения в формате `Y-m-d`.
При фильтрации пытаюсь подставить переменную `$dattw` с текущей датой, для того чтобы из массива выгрузить все значения которые больше текущей даты.

Фильтр не срабатывает и выгружает все значения, **если вместо переменной `$dattw` ввожу напрямую значение `2015-11-30`** фильтр благополучно работает, выгружая необходимые мне даты. 
Помогите где ошибка?

```
<?php   
    $dattw = date("Y-m-d");
    $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('dateevent');
    foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value )
     $filteredarray = array_filter ($mykey_values, function ($item) { return ($item >$dattw); });
    sort ($filteredarray);
    foreach ($filteredarray as $filteredarray => $value)
    echo "$value<br>"; 
?>
```

Comment: а вы сделайте вывод $dattw (в самой анонимной функции) и увидите чему оно равно (или не равно). А потом почитайте про [анонимные функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php), тогда поймете, почему там $dattw отсутствует

Comment: @BOPOH Рекомендую перенести это в ответ (поскольку де-факто это он и есть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анонимная функция ничего не знает о переменной `$dattw`.
Добавить `use ($dattw)`:

```
$filteredarray = array_filter ($mykey_values, function ($item) use ($dattw) { return ($item >$dattw); });
```

В дополнение к комментарию @ВОРОН.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.